# NLog запись в один файл разными стилями

Tags: c#, nlog

Возможно ли при создании лога с помощью NLog записывать информацию в один файл, допустим текстовый, используя разное оформление для вывода (`layout`) в зависимости от слоя (`level`). Допустим оформление для слоя `Error` одно, а для слоя `Debug` - другое.

И соответственно при вызове в приложении

```
Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
//здесь бы использовался более подробный шаблон
//с выводом информации об исключении допустим
logger.Error(ex, "message"); 
//здесь использовалась более упрощенное - дата и сообщение
logger.Debug("message")
```

Answer (score 2):

Если вам надо записывать доп. информацию при наличии исключения - вам поможет [${onexception}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/OnException-Layout-Renderer).

Если же нужна более сложная логика - создайте свой layout renderer, который будет этой логике следовать. За основу можно взять все тот же [${onexception}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/master/src/NLog/LayoutRenderers/Wrappers/OnExceptionLayoutRendererWrapper.cs) и сделать на его основе ${onerror}, ${onwarn}, ${oninfo} и т.д.

Но, сколько я ни использую NLog - а ни разу с такой необходимостью не сталкивался. Обычно, напротив, лучше держать логи однообразными. Возможно, вам и правда следует разные уровни попросту разбить по разным файлам.

Comment: Дополнительную информацию я извлекаю из ошибки `ex`, например `Exception message : ${exception: format=Message}${newline}`. Просто при вызове debug передаваемой ошибки не будет и хотелось поменять шаблон

Comment: @e1s вам лучше не гадать о наличии или отсутствии ошибки на основе уровня - а просто проверить наличие ошибки. Через ${onexception}

Comment: try ... catch она появится все равно, решил свою проблему создав два targeta которые указывают на один физический файл, не знаю правда "правильный" ли это подход, но на первый взгляд работает

Comment: @e1s скажите, чем вас не устраивает ${onexception}? Такое ощущение, что мы на разных языках говорим... И нет, один физический файл для разных таргетов - не очень хорошая идея.

Comment: Я так и не понял как применять данную конструкцию `${onexception:inner=Layout}`, ее в target надо прописывать как альтернативный Layout?

Comment: Ее надо прописывать внутрь layout. А внутрь этой конструкции прописывается фрагмент сообщения, которое надо выводить при исключении.

Answer (score -1):

мой Nlog.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log" >


  <!-- optional, add some variabeles
  https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#variables
  -->
  <variable name="myvar" value="myvalue"/>

  <!-- 
  See https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file 
  for information on customizing logging rules and outputs.
   -->
  <targets>

    <!-- 
    add your targets here 
    See https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Targets for possible targets.
    See https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Layout-Renderers for the possible layout renderers.
    -->
    <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" layout="${date:format=HH\:mm\:ss}|${level}|${message}" />
    <target name="file"
        xsi:type="File"
        fileName="${basedir}/logs/Log.${level}.current.txt"
        layout="${longdate} ${callsite} ${level}: ${message} ${exception:format=Message,StackTrace} ${stacktrace}"
        archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/archives/log.error.${shortdate}.{#}.txt"
        archiveAboveSize="5242880"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        archiveNumbering = "Rolling"
        maxArchiveFiles="3" />
    <!--
    Writing events to the a file with the date in the filename. 
    <target xsi:type="File" name="f" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
    -->
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!-- add your logging rules here -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console" />
    <!--
    Write all events with minimal level of Debug (So Debug, Info, Warn, Error and Fatal, but not Trace)  to "f"
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="f" />
    -->
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

для разных уровней указаны разные пути. то есть при Debug будет отображение и в консоль, и запись в файл. а при Trace только консоль. нужно учитывать что есть иерархия событий, и более высокие включаю более низкие. но думаю что таргет можно написать и другой путь к файлу